# Is a Replacing GFCI difficult

Tags: electrical, gfci

I have a GFCI outlet in my powder room that needs to be replaced.  Is it significantly more difficult to replace a GFCI than an ordinary outlet?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/28379/46271.  This possible duplicate has your answer.

Comment: The `LOAD` terminals have warning tape on them saying "Do not use - for wizards only" - not exactly, but that's what it means.  If you heed that advice, super easy.  If you want to play "Sorcerer's Apprentice", fairly hard and easy to botch.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you do need to identify the "line" (supply) and "load" (additionally-protected portion of the circuit, i.e. downstream outlets) cables. If they're connected to the wrong terminals the downstream section of the circuit won't be protected.

With a standard outlet, connection location isn't important other than maintaining polarity.

Comment: For example, in our tract house both bathrooms are on one circuit and were protected by a single GFCI receptacle installed in one bathroom, the one closer to the electric panel. In that case I used the "load" connection to go to the farther bathroom. The deficiency in this arrangement is that if there would be a GF trip (we never had one) due to activity in the farther bathroom someone would have to go to the first bathroom to reset the GFCI receptacle. For some reason I later took out the GFCI receptacle and put in a GFCI breaker. A trip now would mean someone going to the garage.